# Curve shortening flow with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

Let $(M^2,g)$ be a 2-dimensional complete Riemannian manifold (e.g. $(\mathbb{R}^2,\delta_{ij})$) and $p,q\in M$ two points with $p\neq q$. Let $\gamma:I\to M$ be a smooth embedded curve starting at $p$ and ending at $q$.

When does the curve shortening flow starting at $\gamma$ converge to a geodesic segment joining $p$ and $q$, i.e. the "shortest" curve joining the two points?

I am aware of Grayson's result that an embedded *closed* curve in a 2-manifold either shrinks to a round point or converges to a geodesic.

What results are known for curve shortening flow for line segments? Is the flow even well defined?

Answer (score 2):

Two references that might help:

(1) "[Midpoint geodesic polygon / Birkhoff curve shortening](https://mathoverflow.net/q/42352/6094)": Bowditch: "The convergence of the Birkhoff process seems to be an open question for Riemanninan 2-manifolds."

---

[image: Three Handles]

---

(2) The paper below explores what they call the *disk flow*, which
replaces arcs of a curve with geodesic segments:

> Hass, Joel, and Peter Scott. "Shortening curves on surfaces." *Topology* 33, no. 1 (1994): 25-43. ([PDF download from Semantic Scholar](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a44f/61a347796ce7694e51bc8d4793159d888f55.pdf).)